# Passing data using FragmentTabHost in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to pass data from one fragment to another fragment.
My code is

```
FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putString("eventId", eventId);
                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
```

How to pass this eventId from this fragment to fragment2(tab2) and how to get this data from fragment2.

Any possibilities ?

Comment: No. you cant set Argument over here. Instead of do this at Fragment where you add to Fragment transaction.

Comment: Thanks for helping @M D.I try it but i am getting null.I need sample..

Comment: Arguments can be read only at the onCreate of the fragments  and viewpager may create fragments in background, you can try implementing a listener in the second fragment using interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Activity` or `Fragment` class that contains `FragmentTabHost`, you can send data to the fragment in a `Bundle`, like so:

```
tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

Bio bio = player.getBio();
Bundle bioBundle = new Bundle();
bioBundle.putParcelable("bio", bio);
tabHost.addTab(createTab(tabHost, "bioTab", R.string.bio), BioFragment.class, bioBundle);
```

You can use the `getArguments()` method in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` inside your target fragments to get the data, like so:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player_bio, container, false);
    ...
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    Bio bio = arguments.getParcelable("bio");
    ...
    return view;
}
```